# Why is the "f" string not changing

Tags: python, file-read

My Problem is on line 25 when it says

```
if conformation == 1:
            for i in range(l, len(lines[k]), 1):
                if lines[k][i].isdigit() or lines[k][i].istitle():
                    f += lines[k][i]
            if f in var:
                print(var[f])
```

What my issue is is that the "f" string isn't being added to and its value stays as "". For context, I'm trying to make my own sort of mini programming language, and I'm trying to make prints read for variables. Every time it loops to set f to the variable name, nothing happens. The only way I get remotely close to finding the variable name is by doing "print(lines[k][i])" before the "if lines[k][i]" condition.

Note: I was using a debugger, and I'm not sure if the "if f in var" condition is even being checked.

Python code that reads my custom programming language:
⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄

```
code = open("HelloWorld.sabo", 'r')
lines = code.readlines()
var = {}

for k in range(0, len(lines), 1):
    conformation = 0
    temp = ""
    temp2 = ""
    if lines[k][0:5] == "print":
        r = 0
        l = 0
        p = False
        f = ""
        for i in lines[k]:
            r += 1
            if not p:
               l += 1
            if i == "(":
                p = True
                conformation += 1
            if i == "\"" and conformation == 1:
                conformation += 1
            if conformation == 2:
                break
        if conformation == 1:
            for i in range(l, len(lines[k]), 1):
                if lines[k][i].isdigit() or lines[k][i].istitle():
                    f += lines[k][i]
            if f in var:
                print(var[f])
        if conformation == 2:
            for i in range(r, len(lines[k]), 1):
                if not lines[k][i] == "\"":
                    f += lines[k][i]
                else:
                    break
            print(f)
    elif lines[k][0:4] == "var ":
        for i in range(4, len(lines[k]), 1):
            if not lines[k][i] == " ":
                temp += lines[k][i]
            else: break
        for i in range(4, len(lines[k])):
            if lines[k][i] == "=":
                conformation = 1
            elif conformation == 1:
                if not lines[k][i] == " ":
                    temp2 += lines[k][i]
                elif not temp2 == "":
                    break
        var[temp] = temp2.strip()
```

Code that is being read by the above script:
⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄

```
var val = hello
print(val)
```

Comment: Note that `str.istitle()` checks if the first character of each word is capitalized. Since there are no capital letters in the input to your program, `istitle()` will never return true. This doesn't seem right. Can you explain what the intended effect was?

Comment: @NickODell I was trying to make it so the input could only have letters or numbers, I didn't realize the `str.istitle()` only did capitals. Either way though(at least from what I've tried), even if I remove the condition it still doesn't help.

Comment: There isn't a digit in your input either. If you add some digits like 'var23', f will be '23'

Comment: I tried a variable with only numbers in the name, and it worked! Maybe the `istitle` is **the** issue and I just did my debugging wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was being a bit dumb with this, but I found out that if I just account for Uppercase and Lowercase characters, then it will work.

```
if lines[k][i].islower() or lines[k][i].isdigit() or lines[k][i].isnumeric() or lines[k][i].istitle():
                f += lines[k][i]
```

I might have gone overboard with the security though I'm just not sure about the difference `isdigit` and `isnumeric`.

Comment: `I'm not sure about the difference` For example, the character "⅕" is not a "digit," but it is "numeric." See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric